# How to cite a proof

Tags: citing, theorems

In my work I am giving a theorem and its proof from a book. I reproduce the proof and alter it slightly but obviously I need to tell the reader that I got it from that book. Where shall I do it? I don't want to say in my proof "This proof closely follows [1]" but need something more elegant that I can use on any other theorems. What is the standard/your favourite way to do this? Currently I alter to say: `begin{proof}[Proof\cite{blah}]` and then list my version.

Sorry if this is irrelevant...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use something like you propose, maybe adding "from" or "see":

```
\begin{proof}[Proof (from {\cite[p.~25]{blah}})]
\begin{proof}[Proof (see {\cite[p.~25]{blah}})]
```

Maybe "from" if the proof is quoted verbatim and "see" if there is some change.

Comment: Citation commands with a prefix/suffix need to be enclosed in braces {}. The Latin prefix "cf." could also be used to indicate that the proof is not simply a restatement of the cited result.

Comment: @user4483: Yes, of course.

Comment: @egreg How could I change this if I wanted the source in ``P?roof (from {\cite{source}})'' to be unitalicized?

Comment: @jdc `Proof \textup{(from \cite{source})}`

Comment: Thank you (if it doesn't violate community standards to thank you in this box)!

Answer (score 1):

If the theorem itself is also from the book, I would use

```
\begin{theorem}[Theorem 2.5 of~\cite{book}]
```

where "2.5" is of course the theorem number as it is typeset within the book.  Alternatively, you could give a page number.

How this is typeset will depend on your bibliography style/citation format.  For some formats this may look better:

```
\begin{theorem}[\cite[Theorem 2.5]{book}]
```